# How to do some custom formatting in YAPF

Tags: python-3.8, yapf

I am looking some custom formatting along with YAPF.
.e.g. "add new line before if and for statements"
Is there any way we can create custom Knobs
https://github.com/google/yapf#knobs

Comment: It doesn't look like there is an interface for that, of course you can add something manually to https://github.com/google/yapf/blob/212c5b5ad8e172d2d914ae454c121c89cccbcb35/yapf/yapflib/reformatter.py (it is basically a long chain of if-then formatting rules).